# quantregForest setting seed

Tags: r, random-forest, quantreg

I am trying to run reproducible results with quantregForest but can't get the same results. Is there a way of setting the seed in this function?

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(500), ncol = 10)
y <- rnorm(50) 
nodesize = floor(length(y) / 4)
set.seed(71)
a <- quantregForest(x,y, keep.inbag=TRUE,nodesize=nodesize,ntree=2000, nthreads = 1)
b <- quantregForest(x,y, keep.inbag=TRUE,nodesize=nodesize,ntree=2000, nthreads = 1)
testthat::expect_equal(a, b)
```

a is not equal to b

Comment: Just add your line `set.seed(71)` in between `a <- ...` and `b <- ...`

Comment: Wow thanks, didn't realise it would be that simple. Does the seed get removed/overwritten when running this function?

Comment: Well, the seed changes every time you use it. Otherwise every call to `rnorm()` would result in the same numbers

Comment: oh, of course that makes sense. Thanks so much for your help!